# mathspec with lowercase greek italic symbol std

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, mathspec

I would like to get the `greek symbols` are in `symbol std italic` font. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times LT Std}
\setmathsfont{Symbol Std-Italic}
\setmathsfont(Digits){Times LT Std}
\setmathsfont(Latin)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Times LT Std}
\setmathsfont(Greek)[Lowercase=Regular]{Symbol Std}

\begin{document}
This is some sample text. $\alpha$ Sample lowercase Italic $\beta$.
\end{document}
```

Or can i use `unicode-math` package, how?

Comment: And what do you get now?

Comment: @Michael: I have getting all the lowercase greek symbol font are in `cmmi` and not without `symbold std italic`. I have installed `symbol std italic` font on my system.